# zip -P command not working to create password protect zip file

Tags: php, linux, zip

First i made a script for creating a zip file of the particular directory and then remove all files except zip from the directory that working fine.

But now i implemented the zip -P password command into the script to make it password protected that is not working,

When i tried to extract the file after downloading it is extracting without asking any password. Please make me correct to tell me whats wrong i am doing.

this is how i tried to do that:

```
exec('cd ' . escapeshellarg($directory_location) . ' ; zip -r ' .escapeshellarg($directory_location).'/'.escapeshellarg($zipname) . ' * ; '.$command.' '.escapeshellarg($zipname).' chmod 777 '.escapeshellarg($zipname).'; find . -type f -not -name \''.escapeshellarg($zipname).'\' -exec rm \{\} \; ' );
```

this is the output:

```
cd '/home/example/public_html/downloads/9c1f97ab931b9f4dc461c164f119a340/20' ; zip -r '/home/example/public_html/downloads/9c1f97ab931b9f4dc461c164f119a340/20'/'Xm18u_download.zip' * ; zip -P 'testPassword' '/home/example/public_html/downloads/9c1f97ab931b9f4dc461c164f119a340/20'/'Xm18u_download.zip' 'Xm18u_download.zip' ; 'Xm18u_download.zip' chmod 777 'Xm18u_download.zip'; find . -type f -not -name ''Xm18u_download.zip'' -exec rm \{\} \;
```

### CLOSED ( Solution found )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, this is working with recursive mode zip file creation:

```
zip -r -P <password>
```

for me it is:

```
$command = '-P '.escapeshellarg($password);
exec('cd ' . escapeshellarg($directory_location) . ' ; zip -r '.$command.' ' .escapeshellarg($directory_location).'/'.escapeshellarg($zipname) . ' * ; '.escapeshellarg($zipname).' chmod 777 '.escapeshellarg($zipname).'; find . -type f -not -name \''.escapeshellarg($zipname).'\' -exec rm \{\} \; ' );
```

Hope this is helpful for someone else ;)